# Browserlink CSS autosync not working ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, browser-link

I cannot get the CSS to sync in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Here's what I do:

- Create brand new application using MS template
- Launch the generated template (app.UseBrowserLink() is present)
- Try to modify site.css by setting the background-color to yellow
- Nothing happens

I have the CSS autosync enabled, in the browserlink dashboard I can see the connected browser and I can also use the Refresh button on the dashboard

[image: screen from VS]
.

Funny enough, when I create a new project using the classic old ASP.NET MVC template, CSS autosync does indeed work, however I cannot make it run on ASP.NET Core template

I've also tried installing the BrowserLink.Loader assembly and referencing thatone but to no avail...

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/BrowserLink/issues/62) with Visual studio, and as of October ["CSS Auto-Sync isn't supported on ASP.NET Core yet"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/134308/view.html).

Something you could try is to use Chrome's "add folder to workspace" feature as suggested [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130950/auto-sync-css-not-working-on-vs2017-v1540-for-aspn.html) and you can also try [enabling browser link for static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#enabling-browser-link-for-static-html-files) which has helped some people to make it work.

You can also vote on [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/31961509-auto-sync-css-not-working-on-vs2017-v15-4-0-for-as) to encourage Microsoft to implement CSS autosync for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: This went totally below my radar. Thank you!